# Rails 4 trivial views vs render :json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there any advantage of using a trivial view such as

```
# controllers/abc.rb
@myModelList = Model.all

# views/abc/index.json.jbuilder
json.array @myModelList
```

Versus

```
# controllers/abc.rb
render json: Model.all.to_json
```

This is of course a very simplified example but it highlight my question.

If the view rendering is as simple as applying `.to_json` to a list of model (as it is often the case in small API), is there any advantage in using a one liner view over just rendering the json in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to customize the JSON by formatting a string/date or adding an association for example, then it is better to do that logic in the view layer and not the controller layer.

Comment: Agreed, but my question is **If my rendering logic is only .tojson**. Doing some logic and formatting in the view rendering is not a **trivial view**.

Comment: Your rendering right now might be, but what if it's not in the future? What if some of your models render trivially but some of them don't, will you use the controller sometimes and the view other times? Use the conventions Rails is built upon and you will be better off in the future.

Answer (score 0):

if json output for every request is the same, you should use the 2nd approach: `render json: Model.all`

If each request need a different json format, you should use the first one